# What is the expected memory used by a skeleton android app?

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, heap-memory

In trying to understand memory usage in android apps (for the purpose of profiling my game), I created a new android project in eclipse, then ran it and looked at the memory usage.

it seems as though even a skeleton app uses over 2.5MB of memory.  A dump of the dominator tree from MAT eclipse is pasted at the end of this post. Does this make sense?

If I'm working with a hard limit of (usually) 16MB, and should leave room for other apps, what's the ballpark memory figure for my own code?

cheers

| Class Name | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl @ 0x40462d80 | 24 | 228,704 | 10.43% |
| class android.text.Html$HtmlParser @ 0x40185640 System Class | 8 | 126,632 | 5.77% |
| org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider @ 0x400eaf50 | 112 | 62,688 | 2.86% |
| class org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Services @ 0x400e1370 System Class | 32 | 53,880 | 2.46% |
| class com.android.internal.R$styleable @ 0x40086f00 System Class | 4,592 | 38,288 | 1.75% |
| class android.R$styleable @ 0x400520c8 System Class | 4,512 | 37,856 | 1.73% |
| class libcore.icu.TimeZones$CachedTimeZones @ 0x40440680 System Class | 16 | 37,712 | 1.72% |
| class android.content.res.Resources @ 0x40071678 System Class | 40 | 37,176 | 1.69% |
| class android.text.AutoText @ 0x40170bd0 System Class | 56 | 31,656 | 1.44% |
| org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyStore @ 0x4024c830 | 16 | 16,200 | 0.74% |
| char[8060] @ 0x400b8a08 Africa/AbidjanAfrica/AccraAfrica/Addis_AbabaAfrica/AlgiersAfrica/AsmaraAfrica/AsmeraAfrica/BamakoAfrica/BanguiAfrica/BanjulAfrica/BissauAfrica/BlantyreAfrica/BrazzavilleAfrica/BujumburaAfrica/CairoAfrica/CasablancaAfrica/CeutaAfrica/ConakryAfrica/DakarAfri... | 16,136 | 16,136 | 0.74% |
| class org.apache.harmony.security.utils.AlgNameMapper @ 0x40084650 System Class | 24 | 15,336 | 0.70% |
| android.content.res.StringBlock @ 0x40171268 | 32 | 12,088 | 0.55% |
| class org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESFastEngine @ 0x40076930 System Class | 64 | 9,440 | 0.43% |
| class android.opengl.GLES20 @ 0x400313a0 System Class | 1,216 | 8,480 | 0.39% |
| class org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnectionImpl @ 0x40046ee0 System Class | 8 | 7,776 | 0.35% |
| class org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.util.ZoneInfoDB @ 0x400a13a0 System Class | 40 | 7,640 | 0.35% |
| class java.lang.System @ 0x40010540 System Class | 24 | 7,360 | 0.34% |
| class com.ibm.icu4jni.util.LocaleData @ 0x4000e0b0 System Class | 8 | 6,768 | 0.31% |
| class android.opengl.GLES10 @ 0x4002e330 System Class | 968 | 6,768 | 0.31% |
| class javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10 @ 0x4002b3a8 System Class | 952 | 6,656 | 0.30% |
| class java.lang.Character$UnicodeBlock @ 0x40217b78 System Class | 512 | 6,112 | 0.28% |
| class android.provider.Settings$System @ 0x401680a0 System Class | 568 | 6,008 | 0.27% |
| org.apache.harmony.security.provider.crypto.CryptoProvider @ 0x40151888 | 112 | 5,512 | 0.25% |

---

Comment: What platform are you developing on? Depending on where you got 16mb from, its probably a 16mb cap per app, not for all apps. Using 2.5mb just for the barebones app is not surprising, resources alone can be several times that in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem here. A basic app will use a number of megs of ram.

> If I'm working with a hard limit of (usually) 16MB, and should leave
>   room for other apps

You don't need to worry about other apps. The android OS will sort that. And the minimum is usually 16 megs per app, not total apps as you said.